# Update the layout on change in the height of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a page where there are many divs arranged one by one and they are under a masonry effect.

masonry is working good but the only problem is that the divs have a place to make a comment and whenever we make a comment the height of the div is increased but masonary dosent rearranges the divs.

the div is reloading by ajax

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $container = $('#REATinsidEpoASttt78');
      $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry({
              itemSelector : '.realFLOAtingPOSTSA',
              columnWidth : 350
          });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

this is for the masonry and now for the reloading div

```
function formsubmitionbyajax(obj){
    var id=$(obj).attr("id");
    var currentform = $(obj);
    $('#COMMlo'+id).show();
    $.ajax({ type: 'post',
        url: 'home_formhandler1.php',
        data: currentform.serialize(),
        success: function(){
            $("#mainDIV"+id).load('home.php #mainDIV'+id);
        } 
    });
    return false;   
}
```

My html looks like

```
<div id="REATinsidEpoASttt78">
  <div class="realFLOAtingPOSTSA">
    <div id="mainDIVffrmMN<?=$THE_DTAinar['id']?>">
       something from database....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

can any one please tell me how to rearrange the divs whenever there is any change in the height of any div.update the layout 
currently i am using like

```
var container = document.querySelector('#REATinsidEpoASttt78');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    columnWidth: 350
});
setTimeout(function () { msnry.layout();   }, 2000);
```

this is working but it arranges the div aftera delay of 2 seconds 
iam searching for something better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [resize event](http://api.jquery.com/resize) like,

```
var container = document.querySelector('#REATinsidEpoASttt78');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                 columnWidth: 350
           });
$('#REATinsidEpoASttt78').on('resize',function () {  // use resize
   msnry.layout();
});
```